# How to execute a JUnit package inside a jar

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a project where a one single package contains all JUnit tests. (But those are not in src/test, but in src/main). In eclipse environment I can select the package and do run as JUnit. Then it will execute classes in alphabetical order. But what I want to do now is to do the same but using the jar i built. How can i do it ? (in command line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest solution to this problem I can think of is to add a suite class to your src code and run the `suite` from command line. If you want you can use the dynamic classpath search that `cpsuite` gives you and do the following (this will also be more generic and not involves in adding suite class to your project):

Write a jar with with this class:

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite.IncludeJars;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@IncludeJars(true)
public class MySuite {
}
```

Include this jar in the classpath and run something like this from the command line:

```
java -cp <path-to-where MySuite jar>:<path-to-tested-jar + all its dependencies>:<path-to cpsuite.jar + all its dependencies> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <full-package-name-to-where-MySuite-is-in>.MySuite
```